# Why can I preview and open some .docx attachments on Trello but not others?

Tags: google-drive, trello

When .docx files are added to Trello cards, I generally click to open the preview and from there open the file in Google Drive. However, there are some .docx files that say "Whoops! There was a problem displaying this image." and I am unable to open them in Google Drive (I only have the option to download to my computer).

I know that the .docx files that don't preview were not actually created in Word, but were Google Doc files that were downloaded to the a computer and then uploaded to the card. Could this be causing the issue?

Does anyone have a solution to resolve this? Or is the only solution to simply link to Google Drive instead of adding the attachment from the computer?